# How to find the top n quantities within a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose in the table mentioned below, I wanted to select the top 3 quantities and if there are duplicates, I want them too and the required table is mentioned below too.

For this requirement, I tried something like the SQL below.

```
select name, quantity
from employee
order by name,quantity DESC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

But I'm not able to get any meaningful output. BTW I'm using postgres.

All I need is employee info along with quantities with 3 max quantities along with ties if any.

````
NAME | Quantity
---------
AAA     500
AAA     500
AAA     400
AAA     300
AAA     200
AAA     100


Required Table:

NAME | Quantity
--------------
AAA     500
AAA     500
AAA     400
AAA     300
```
````

Comment: you can't orde by name to get the higrst quantities

Comment: try this : select *
from tabl where quantity in 
(select distinct quantity from tabl order by quantity desc limit 3
)
order by Quantity desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `dense_rank`.

```
select "NAME"
      ,"Quantity"
from  (
       select *
             ,dense_rank() over(order by "Quantity" desc) as dr
       from t
       ) t
where  dr <= 3
```

| NAME | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 500 |
| AAA | 500 |
| AAA | 400 |
| AAA | 300 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ddab8886142c5e9477881ea20dc90590)

Comment: that is not <= 3 as a result

Comment: Any other way without using functions like dense_rank()?

Comment: @nbk : I did not get. What modification do I have to do?

Comment: @nbk I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DannySlor: Any other alternatives for dense_rank(), I can't use those functions.

Comment: rank row numner starts with 1, sp your outer query should only return 3 tows per name not 4 not 5

Comment: @nbk you might want to take a second look at the OP request.

Comment: @gautam why can't you use them?

Comment: @DannySlor : That is the instruction, only use the 5 aggregate functions. No special functions are permitted.

Comment: @gautam this should've been a part of the post. Please accept the answer and open a new post.